# SWT grid layout issue

Tags: java, layout, swt

so I've been working on a SWT dialog. It should look something like this:

```
/----------------------------------\
| Label1                           |
| [_Text_box_1__________][Button1] |
|                                  |
| Label2                           |
| |---------------------|[Button2] |
| |  List 1             |[Button3] |
| |---------------------|          |
|                                  |
| Label3                           |
| |---------------------|[Button4] |
| |  List 2             |[Button5] |
| |---------------------|          |
|                                  |
|                 [ Ok ] [ Cancel] |
\----------------------------------/
```

I've experimented with RowLayout and nested Composites for the TextBox + Buttons but it doesn't seem to fill the space horizontally. I've also tried GridLayout with both one column and nested Composites and with two columns but it never seems to work.

Can anyone suggest an approach that might work for me please?

---

EDIT:
I've managed to get it to work with fixed size:

```
    Display display = parent.getDisplay();
    Shell shell = new Shell(parent, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.TITLE);
    shell.setText("Text");

        RowLayout layout = new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL);
        layout.marginBottom = 15;
        layout.marginTop = 15;
        layout.marginLeft = 15;
        layout.marginRight = 15;
        layout.spacing = 5;
        layout.wrap = true;
        layout.fill = true;
        layout.justify = false;
        shell.setLayout(layout);

        Label label1 = new Label(shell, SWT.LEFT);
        label1.setText("Label 1");
        RowData data = new RowData();
        data.width = 400;
        label1.setLayoutData(data);

        Composite comp1 = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        layout = new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL);
        layout.fill = true;
        comp1.setLayout(layout);
        Text text1 = new Text(comp1, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
        data = new RowData();
        data.width = 400;
        text1.setLayoutData(data);
        Button button1 = new Button(comp1, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
        button1.setText("Button 1");

        new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

        Label label2 = new Label(shell, SWT.LEFT);
        label2.setText("Label 2");

        Composite comp2 = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        layout = new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL);
        comp2.setLayout(layout);

        List list1 = new List(comp2, SWT.BORDER);
        data = new RowData();
        data.width = 400;
        data.height = 150;
        list1.setLayoutData(data);
        Composite comp3 = new Composite(comp2, SWT.NONE);
        comp3.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
        Button button2 = new Button(comp3, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
        button2.setText("Button 2");
        data = new RowData();
        data.width = 70;
        button2.setLayoutData(data);
        Button button3 = new Button(comp3, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
        button3.setText("Button 3");
        button3.setLayoutData(data);

        new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

        Label label3 = new Label(shell, SWT.LEFT);
        label3.setText("Label 3");

        Composite comp4 = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        layout = new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL);
        comp4.setLayout(layout);

        List list2 = new List(comp4, SWT.BORDER);
        data = new RowData();
        data.width = 400;
        data.height = 150;
        list2.setLayoutData(data);
        Composite comp5 = new Composite(comp4, SWT.NONE);
        comp5.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
        Button button4 = new Button(comp5, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
        button4.setText("Button 4");
        data = new RowData();
        data.width = 70;
        button4.setLayoutData(data);
        Button button5 = new Button(comp5, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
        button5.setText("Button 5");
        button5.setLayoutData(data);

        new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

        Composite comp6 = new Composite(shell, SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        comp6.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
        Button cancelButton = new Button(comp6, SWT.CENTER);
        cancelButton.setText("Cancel");
        data = new RowData();
        data.width = 70;
        cancelButton.setLayoutData(data);
        Button okButton = new Button(comp6, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
        okButton.setText("OK");
        okButton.setLayoutData(data);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this without falling back on width hints (which should only be used if there's no other option):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new MyDialog(new Shell(new Display())).open();
}

private static class MyDialog extends Dialog
{
    protected MyDialog(Shell parentShell)
    {
        super(parentShell);
        setShellStyle(getShellStyle() | SWT.RESIZE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureShell(Shell newShell)
    {
        super.configureShell(newShell);
        newShell.setText("Stackoverflow");
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent)
    {
        Composite comp = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);

        // Part one
        Label one = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
        one.setText("Label1");
        new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
        Text textOne = new Text(comp, SWT.BORDER);
        textOne.setText("Textbox1");
        Button buttonOne = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
        buttonOne.setText("Button1");

        // Part two
        Label two = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
        two.setText("Label2");
        new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
        List listOne = new List(comp, SWT.BORDER);
        listOne.add("List1");
        Composite buttonCompOne = new Composite(comp, SWT.NONE);
        Button buttonTwoOne = new Button(buttonCompOne, SWT.PUSH);
        buttonTwoOne.setText("Button2");
        Button buttonTwoTwo = new Button(buttonCompOne, SWT.PUSH);
        buttonTwoTwo.setText("Button3");

        // Part three
        Label three = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
        three.setText("Label3");
        new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
        List listTwo = new List(comp, SWT.BORDER);
        listTwo.add("List2");
        Composite buttonCompTwo = new Composite(comp, SWT.NONE);
        Button buttonThreeOne = new Button(buttonCompTwo, SWT.PUSH);
        buttonThreeOne.setText("Button4");
        Button buttonThreeTwo = new Button(buttonCompTwo, SWT.PUSH);
        buttonThreeTwo.setText("Button5");

        // Layout stuff
        comp.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        layout.marginWidth = 0;
        layout.marginHeight = 0;
        buttonCompOne.setLayout(layout);
        layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        layout.marginWidth = 0;
        layout.marginHeight = 0;
        buttonCompTwo.setLayout(layout);
        textOne.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        buttonOne.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.TOP, false, true));
        listOne.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        listTwo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        buttonCompOne.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.TOP, false, true));
        buttonCompTwo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.TOP, false, true));

        return comp;
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

Small:

[image]

Large:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out! Is there a way to stop the textbox from expanding vertically?

Comment: @Alternatic `textOne.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));`